# How to write grammars for Lexical and Syntax error recovery?

Tags: compiler-construction, javacc

I'm trying to write grammars for lexical and syntax error recovery using Javacc and don't know how to use the error_skipto() grammar.I'm first trying to recover errors just from multiple lines of print() or in my language ,"syout()" statements, to understand how it works and apply it to the rest of my grammars but I cant get the outputs i expect, also, my try-catch statement doesn't catch the `TokenMnger` error inside the grammar I declare it in, instead is catched in the one that is declared in the main function of my parser class

The structure of my source code in my language would look like this

```
//source code
start
 syout(1)~
 syout(2)
 syout(3)
 syout(4)~
over
//source code
//the "~" symbol is the line-end indicator,and "start" and "over" delimits
//the "main function"
```

Im producing 3 consecutive syntax errors

And my grammar for the syout() statements is the following,passing to the error_skip() grammar the "~" symbol and the exception

```
void imprimir():
{}
 {  
    try{
     <DATA_OUT><OPEN_PAREN>(<NUM_INT>|
     <NUM_FLOAT>|<CHAR>|<STRING>|<IDENTIFIER>)
     <CLOSE_PAREN><LINE_END>     
     }catch(ParseException e){
        error_skipto(LINE_END, e);
     }catch(TokenMgrError err){
        error_skipto2(LINE_END,err);
    }   
}
```

I'm using the error_skipto() grammar from the Javacc documentation, and I added an argument for printing the exact error message

```
JAVACODE
void error_skipto(int kind, ParseException ex){

  System.out.println(ex.toString());  
  Token t;
  do {
    t=getNextToken();

  } while (t.kind!=kind);
}
```

For this source code, I'm supposed to get 3 error messages from the parser, but i only get one,the first.But when i produce non-consecutive errors, I get all the errors.Also, if i produce a lexical error, it is not catched inside the try-catch block in the grammar, but instead is catched in the main function inside the class of my parser.

Comment: I'd really suggest turning on the various debug options to get a better idea of what's going on.  One thing to keep in mind is that the lexer can be well ahead of the parser.

Comment: It's not clear what the 3 errors are.  I only see 2.  There is a missing `LINE_END` after `2)` and another missing `LINE_END` after `3)`.  The error recovery from the first error causes all tokens to be skipped until the second `~`.  So of course the second error is skipped over.  One solution might be to emply a different error recovery strategy when the error is a missing `END_LINE`; e.g. don't skip any tokens.

Comment: The `error_skip_to` routine should probably exit when `t.kind == 0`, since this indicated the end of file.  As it is, I think you will get an infinite loop if there are no more tokens of kind `kind` in the file.